# Percent of internet running Google Native Client?

Tags: google-nativeclient

Anyone have numbers on how many machines / % of internet uses have Google Native Client?

I'm curious about google NaCL as a platform: it seems to combine the best of the web (just a webpage, accessible on any machine) and desktop apps (OpenGL, C/C++ power). The only question is -- what percent of the world actually use it.

Anyone have data on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately its pretty much dead now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's safe to say it's well under 1%. Does the actual percentage (.001%? .01%?) make any difference?

The technology might or might not have much merit, but you've asked the question way to early, before it's had a chance to show it's colours.

P.S.: BTW, you can make an educated guess about the number of users by the number of times the "nativeclient" tag has been used on SO. ;)

Answer (score 3):

As of this posting Chrome holds about 25% of the market.  I assume a little less than that will be NaCl enabled.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that stumbles on to this page, note that [Native Client is (now) automatically enabled for applications that are installed from the Chrome Web Store](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/running#flag), but:

> To enable Native Client for applications that are not installed from
>   the Chrome Web Store, you must explicitly turn on the Native Client flag...

This changes the equation quite a bit given that "[chrome is the most popular browser](http://www.theverge.com/2012/5/21/3033566/chrome-most-popular-browser-weekly-may-2012)". If you deploy via the web store, you should be effectively unrestricted by this feature toggle (assuming your users have the latest versions of chrome, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

Well, at least ~50 Native Client developers must have it installed.